# How to build MySql to install mysql.h

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, build, include

I am building MySql from source. But it does not install mysql.h into /usr/include/mysql.
I know that I can install it with libmysqlclient-dev package but I want to install it within the build process.

What I tried is this:
In a build directory:

```
../configure
cmake -DDOWNLOAD_BOOST=1 -DWITH_BOOST=../mysql-server/downloads -DWITHOUT_SERVER=ON -DWITH_TESTS=OFF ../
sudo cmake install ../
```

What am I missing here?